# Adjective for withstanding the passage of time

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective meaning that an idea or object has longevity, or will still be relevant in the future?

(I believe I've heard such a word, but I can't think of it at the moment.)

Usage example:

> While this textbook is interesting, it does not seem particularly ***[?]***; five years from now, it will be useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of possible synonyms:

> eternal, lasting, permanent, enduring, abiding, immortal, everlasting,
>   ceaseless, immutable, indestructible, undying, ageless, imperishable,
>   changeless.

The word required in your example, however, might be *definitive*, which carries the sense of being authoritative.

Comment: Another synonym: "transcendent". - Even "poetic" might be of service here. Context: I remember seeing someone's remarks once about people writing interesting, useful books, which will be widely read, but which won't outweigh so much as the idle sigh of a true poet. (Can anyone pin down this quote? - a casual googling didn't bring it to light.)

Answer (score 6):

Two additional ideas would be:

- [*timeless*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timeless) ("not affected by time; ageless")
- [*future-proof*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/future_proof) ("designed not to be obsolete in the future")

Answer (score 3):

I like *enduring*; 'twas the first word that entered my mind.

Barrie listed many good candidates, but I'd like to add one more: *persistent*.

> **persistent** |pərˈsistənt| (adj)
>   1. continuing firmly or obstinately in a course of action in spite of difficulty or opposition
>   2. continuing to exist or endure over a prolonged period

Answer (score 1):

The word would be *longevous*, but this is archaic.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research for the word. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/answering).

Answer (score 0):

One good word is *durable*.

[Merriam-Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/durable):

> able to exist for a long time without significant deterioration.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a word like that too, and finally figured out that the word I was trying to think of was **[long-standing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longstanding)**.